# computed property displays as plain text in vue

Tags: vue.js

How can I display the title with spans as HTML not plain text.

**Code:**

```
spanTitle() {
    return this.title.replace(/([A-Za-z0-9'<>/]+)/g, '<span>$1</span>');
}

{{ spanTitle }}
```

**this.title = "Upcomming Events"**

**spanTitle currently displays as:**

```
<span>Upcomming</span> <span>Events</span>
```

Comment: Please share more code and details about the use case

Comment: This is what v-html is for

Answer (score 1):

To fix the issue, I used the v-html directive

Answer (score 1):

you can do using ,

but a better way to do is

```
spanTitle() {
    return this.title.replace(/([A-Za-z0-9'<>/]+)/g, $1);
}
```

and use span in template like

```
<span> {{ spanTitle  }} </span>
```